# What is "angular art"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've stumbled upon "angular art" in following sentence:

> Everywhere there is something to delight the eye — not tchotchkes, but art. Eccentric art, angular art, modern art, all a signifier of personal style.
>   — From an article in Palm Beach Post, January 12, 2013

Though I can understand that "angular art" is an art style and get an idea what sort of art it is by googling "angular art", I was not able to find more or less clear definition of this art style and when it and its name entered the language.

Probably this question is more about art than about English but anyway maybe somebody can clarify this for me.

Comment: But it's so obvious. It's art that you have to look at from an angle in order to make sense

Comment: As you have noted, this is more about _art_ than _English_. It does not really appear to be a mainstream term either. You can try to find a suitable stack for your question [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#arts) or [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=art).

Comment: http://goo.gl/v6HDt

Comment: Art with few curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *angular art* is simply an adjective applied to a noun and isn't used as an actual defined term in the art world.

As such, it may not make sense to find when it entered the language. But *angular* dates from 1598 and *art* from c.1300. Here's a snippet of the 1920 *[Highways and byways in London](http://books.google.com/books?id=7ZIKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22angular%20art%22&dq=%22angular%20art%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nyBMUdXbNsmN4gTiu4DYBQ&redir_esc=y)* by Emily Constance (Baird) Cook:

> Therefore, at Millbank, they are but rarely gowned in **angular "art serge,"** and are but seldom be-spectacled and be-catalogued. Neither are the Hypatia like girl-lecturers at all evident.

And a snippet of a 1929 report on the *[The Caribou Eskimos](http://books.google.com/books?id=RBNbAAAAYAAJ)*:

> On the North Pacific coast combs are used which, with their ornamented handle, may recall later Eskimo forms, with the difference which the **angular art** of the Northwest Indians must necessarily, involve.

And finally the *[Princeton Alumni Weekly](http://books.google.com/books?id=RBNbAAAAYAAJ)* (Volume 40, 1939):

> These unsophisticated ballads have an imagery and charm, as appealing as the quaint and **angular art** of Gothic times, and will be indispensable reading matter not only for the student of literature, but for all who love legends, those delicate fairytales of an untutored society.

Radu Miro suggests it means art you need to look at an angle in order to make sense, but I think it's any art which exhibits stark, pointy, angular edges, such as is seen in this [Google image search](http://goo.gl/v6HDt) mplungjan provided, and is to be found in modern art.